# Table Row Height

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a page with a table, and I want its layout to look like this:

```
+------------+--------------+----------------------------------+
| 200px wide |  300px wide  |         Remaining width          |
|  2 rows    |    1 row     |              1 row               |
|Page height |              | Height of image scaled to width  |
|            +--------------+----------------------------------+
|            |                 Remaining width                 |
|            |                 Remaining height                |
|            |                 1 row, 2 columns                |
+------------+-------------------------------------------------+
```

I seem to be able to get everything working except limiting the height of the table to the page height. How do I make the table height equal to the page height?

Here is a [sample page](http://jsbin.com/iyafi4/edit).

I could do this in two minutes with jQuery, but I really don't want to have to use Javascript do something this simple.

EDIT: Only tested in Firefox. It may or may not work in other browsers.

Comment: I'm not saying it makes your problem easier, but you shouldn't use tables for layout.

Comment: I think you could make all this easier using div boxes... you can make the height of the table by using this in the table tab:  style="height:100%;"

Comment: I think your requirements contain a contradiction: if the height of the image is always proportional to the width of the cell, then it's possible leaving no room for the bottom row in wide shallow browser windows.

Comment: @NGLN I will accept any behavior if the browser is shallower than the image.

Comment: Which browsers must this work in? (it looks like "only Firefox", but I'm just double-checking)

Comment: tables are pain in the arse. use divs with css it's the easiest way

Comment: @zzlawlz If you can come up with a solution that does this exact same things with divs, I'll accept it. @thirtydot IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Safari

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this?

```
<table width="100%" height ="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
  <tr>
    <td width="200px" rowspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="300px">&nbsp;</td>
    <td width="44%">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```